# How can I scroll down using xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll

How can I scroll down as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: You want to increase scroll content size or frame?

Comment: I should have added that I'm a newbiw :) Where shall I find these?

Comment: Then you can increase content size of scroll.

Comment: [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height+requiredheight)]

Comment: Don't hate me yet, but where shall I put it? :)

Comment: Please post some code so may be I can help you

Comment: I made 1 page, I'm using Objective-C .. the thing is, the files on the left don't hold any of what I made!

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lt1o_k9jUw
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this

```
_categoryItemScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(310, 600);
```